# Ordering ambiguity in the spinor helicity formalism of scattering amplitudes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, field-theory, scattering, spinors, amplituhedron

I am following Nima's course on "Quantum mechanics and spacetime, total positivity and motives", and I wonder if there's a direct way to understand the ordering ambiguity when we are summing over different channels. In other words, how do we know if we should use $\langle12\rangle$ or $\langle21\rangle$.
I know it doesn't matter when we are just computing one diagram, but my question is when we have to sum over different channels as Nima does in the course.

Comment: Could you add a link to the reference?